# Omit majority of columns from tables in CakePHP schema

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have a legacy database linked to a CakePHP (2.5.3) application. The database has a LOT of columns in all of its tables, many of which are completely unused (for example in one table I only need 2 columns out of 80 blank ones), so as a result I always have to specify 'fields' whenever I run a query. I read elsewhere that I can unset the fields by using code like this in the model:

```
function beforeFind($query) {
  $this->schema();

  unset($this->_schema['ColumnName']);
  unset($this->_schema['ColumnName2']);
  etc.
}
```

And this seems to work okay, the problem is that I am using 80+ lines of code to unset columns when really I only need to set two. Is there a way to force CakePHP to let me manually define the columns in the schema?

I have tried declaring the $_schema variable at the start of the model and that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Override Model::schema

[Model::schema](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1378-L1403) is the method which tells CakePHP what fields exist, you need only override it to say explicitly what fields it should contain, or filter out the fields you don't want.

e.g.:

```
function schema($field = false) {
    if (!is_array($this->_schema) || $field === true) {
        parent::schema();
        $keepTheseKeys = array_flip(['Column1', 'Column2']);
        $this->_schema = array_intersect_key($this->_schema, $keepTheseKeys);
    }

    return parent::schema($field);
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! It's working perfectly, though I had to make a couple changes to the code for it to work for me - there are too many closing brackets on the if statement and I had to replace $this->schema with $this->_schema. I have submitted an edit to your post.

Comment: I am not immune to typos =).